# Where in the Source code for OpenCV is the Size Class?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I grepped all over the Opencv directory for `Size::`  `CV_EXPORTS SIZE` `Size::width` but all I can find is the Template class `Size_`, Same as in the Documentation. I would like to view the source code because I'm adding improvements to the OpenCV library and this information would be useful.  On Ubuntu Trusty I am running grep like this:

```
grep -r 'CV_EXPORTS SIZE' .
```

from the modules directory in the root folder

Thanks in advance for any takers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh, that's a deep source tree. Anyway, [opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp) has:

```
/*!
The 2D size class

The class represents the size of a 2D rectangle, image size, matrix size etc.
Normally, cv::Size ~ cv::Size_<int> is used.
*/
template<typename _Tp> class Size_
{
 //! various constructors
    Size_();
    Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height);
    Size_(const Size_& sz);
    Size_(const Point_<_Tp>& pt);

    Size_& operator = (const Size_& sz);
    //! the area (width*height)
    _Tp area() const;

    //! conversion of another data type.
    template<typename _Tp2> operator Size_<_Tp2>() const;

    _Tp width, height; // the width and the height
};

/*!
\typedef
*/
typedef Size_<int> Size2i;
typedef Size_<float> Size2f;
typedef Size_<double> Size2d;
typedef Size2i Size;
```

So, `Size` is an alias for `Size2i`, which is an alias for `Size_<int>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering that for me, can I ask you where the width object of size is defined, is it `Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height)`

Comment: @user3411335 I suspect you're not very familiar with templates. The code you quote means that the `Size_()` constructor takes two arguments of type `_Tp` which is the template type. `_width` and `_height` are simply the names of the constructor's arguments.

Comment: I meant  if you call `Size sz = (Size(640, 480)` and then call `cout << sz.width;` where is that .width object defined,  like in CV_EXPORTS MAT  for example the row object is defined...

Comment: Now I suspect you're not very familiar with C++. `sz.width` accesses the `width` member of the `sz` object, which is of type `Size`. See the class declaration, it declares the two members `width` and `height`.

Comment: so your saying this is what it looks like when members are declared in a template class `Size_(_Tp _width, _Tp _height)`

Comment: @user3411335 Please consider posting new question(s) about these things. And no, the member declaration looks like in any other class, it's the last line in this case, with the comment. I added in the `Size_` code above to make it clearer.

Comment: Great!...Thanks for staying with me until I got it...I accepted your answer and voted you up...Have a good day.